# how can I parse this result in angularjs promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service like this

```
app.service('newsService', function($q, $timeout,$http) {

  this.getNewsName = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var newsId = parseInt(id, 10);

    $timeout(function() {

         $http({
                url: "entry/GetNewsTitle",
                 method: "POST",
                 data: $.param({'id':newsId}),
                 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
                    })
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        deferred.resolve(data.name);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('failed');
                    });
                }, 10);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

The `console.log(deferred.promise)` in another function give me three function "catch" "finally" and "then" but how can I achieve to `data.name` again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
newsService.getNewsName(id).then(function(name) {

});
```

Comment: can u explain more? where i must to us this function?

Comment: @mhadadi if you want to use the name you need to all the function that return a promise and then use `then` to get the value.

Comment: @mhadadi you should call that function in controller, in the place where you want to have that name.

Comment: where is getNewsName function?

Comment: @mhadadi in your service: `this.getNewsName = function(id) {`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should optimize service method to avoid [Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns). You don't need to create dummy deferred object since `$http(...)` already returns a Promise.

The service would look like this:

```
app.service('newsService', function($http) {

    this.getNewsName = function(id) {
        return $http({
            url: "entry/GetNewsTitle",
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param({
                'id': parseInt(id, 10)
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data.name;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('failed');
        });
    };

});
```

Note, that `getNewsName` returns result of `$http`.

Controller consuming this service would then chain to it using Promise API:

```
newsService.getNewsName(123).then(function(name) {
    console.log(name);
});
```